# Как вывести выборку строк в pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, ipython

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как вывести выборку строк, где в столбце (например "Адрес покупателя") были бы значения "1521..."?

Предполагаю это будет через :

```
value_list = ['1521...']

df[df.Адрес покупателя.isin(value_list)].
```

Когда так ввожу - не получается.

И сопутствующий вопрос: как обозвать эту получившуюся выборку, чтобы дальше с ней работать.

Ссылка на файлы .pynb и .xlsx:

http://dropmefiles.com/BoGd5

сам код:

```
value_list = ['1521..']
df[df.Адрес покупателя.isin(value_list)]
```

ошибка:

> SyntaxError: invalid syntax

df:

```
+-----------------+-------------------------------+------------------+
| Сумма заказа, $ |       Адрес покупателя        | Категория товара |
+-----------------+-------------------------------+------------------+
|               2 | Проспект 40 , 152193, RU      | Для детей        |
|            5,01 | Советская, 301282, RU         | Платья           |
|               4 | Ярославская Обл. , 152104, RU | Часы             |
|            6,32 | Ул. Партизанская , 301225, RU | Платья           |
+-----------------+-------------------------------+------------------+
```

Comment: 1. Что значит не получается? Если пишет ошибку - укажите это в вопросе.  2. Весь код и пример данных должны быть в вопросе текстом, а не ссылкой.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ошибка в том, что [`Series.isin(list-like-object)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html) - ищет **полные совпадения** - поэтому в вашем случае ничего найдено не было. Для поиска подстрок можно динамически собрать регулярное выражение (пример ниже) и воспользоваться [`Series.str.contains(regex_pattern)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html).

Пример для Python 3.x (для Python 2.x возможно придется указывать `u''` перед именами столбцов):

```
In [4]: df
Out[4]:
                              Дата покупки  Сумма заказа, $               Адрес покупателя Категория товара
0  Thu Jun 02 2016 20:02:12 GMT+0000 (UTC)             2.00       Проспект 40 , 152193, RU        Для детей
1  Fri Jun 03 2016 10:17:30 GMT+0000 (UTC)             5.01          Советская, 301282, RU           Платья
2  Fri Jun 03 2016 17:15:15 GMT+0000 (UTC)             4.00  Ярославская Обл. , 152104, RU             Часы
3  Fri Jun 03 2016 20:52:54 GMT+0000 (UTC)             6.32  Ул. Партизанская , 301225, RU           Платья
```

Список почтовых индексов:

```
In [5]: zips = ['152193','301225']
```

RegEx (регулярное выражение) для поиска указанных в списке индексов в строке:

```
In [6]: pat = r'\b(?:{})\b'.format('|'.join(zips))

In [7]: pat
Out[7]: '\\b(?:152193|301225)\\b'
```

Ищем в столбце `Адрес покупателя` подстроку по созданному выше RegEx и показываем только те строки, кот. удовлетворяют данному условию:

```
In [8]: df[df['Адрес покупателя'].str.contains(pat)]
Out[8]:
                              Дата покупки  Сумма заказа, $               Адрес покупателя Категория товара
0  Thu Jun 02 2016 20:02:12 GMT+0000 (UTC)             2.00       Проспект 40 , 152193, RU        Для детей
3  Fri Jun 03 2016 20:52:54 GMT+0000 (UTC)             6.32  Ул. Партизанская , 301225, RU           Платья
```

---

Пример поиска по начальным цыфрам индекса:

```
In [27]: zips = ['3012\d+','152193']

In [28]: pat = r'\b(?:{})\b'.format('|'.join(zips))

In [29]: pat
Out[29]: '\\b(?:3012\\d+|152193)\\b'

In [30]: df[df['Адрес покупателя'].str.contains(pat)]
Out[30]:
                              Дата покупки  Сумма заказа, $               Адрес покупателя Категория товара
0  Thu Jun 02 2016 20:02:12 GMT+0000 (UTC)             2.00       Проспект 40 , 152193, RU        Для детей
1  Fri Jun 03 2016 10:17:30 GMT+0000 (UTC)             5.01          Советская, 301282, RU           Платья
3  Fri Jun 03 2016 20:52:54 GMT+0000 (UTC)             6.32  Ул. Партизанская , 301225, RU           Платья
```

---

PS Лучше использовать явную адресацию:

```
df[df['Адрес покупателя'].isin(value_list)]
```

или для Python 2.x в том случае если названия столбцов в `UTF-8`:

```
df[df[u'Адрес покупателя'].isin(value_list)]
```

Адресация столбцов в Pandas через точку **не** работает в следующих случаях:

- имя столбца содержит NON-ASCII символ(ы)
- имя столбца содержит пробелы/табуляции
- имя столбца совпадает с названием метода Pandas или Numpy

Comment: я пробовал так. ошибки нет,но не выводит ничего

Comment: даже если ввести полное значение строки в конкретном столбце в value_list = [' ']

Comment: о,получилось!а как сделать так,чтобы в поиске не полное имя вводить индекса ,а только начало?

Comment: спасибо большое!как всегда очень помогаете!

Comment: @impregis, всегда рад помочь!